# CustomSort strings by using Icomparer

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, mvvm, icomparer

I have to quickly sort items in a ListCollectionView after an Item is added.
I'm trying to use CustomSort and create my own IComparer

The items in the ListCollectionView are of type Scene and I want sort the items based on the SceneNumber which is a property of Scene and a string because it contains numbers followed by letters.

I want to sort

```
1
10
15A
2
30B
4B
4A
```

to

```
1
2
4A
4B
10
15A
30
```

This is what I have so far in the Icomparer

```
public class SortScenes : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {

        if (((Scene)x).SceneNumber > ((Scene)y).SceneNumber)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work by using strings.

I want to achieve following

```
var nums = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
SceneList.OrderBy(x => x.SceneNumber.LastIndexOfAny(nums)).ThenBy(x => x.SceneNumber))
```

but in a IComparer.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider splitting `Scene.SceneNumber` into a e.g. a numeric "main scene" and an alpha "sub scene". Given your Scene declaration, I'm using a RegEx to split the SceneNumber into a numeric and an optional alpha part.

Note that my `IComparer` is an `IComparer<Scene>`, not an `IComparer<string>`.

```
namespace SceneSorter
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sceneList = new List<Scene>
                                {
                                    new Scene { SceneNumber = "1" },
                                    new Scene { SceneNumber = "10" },
                                    new Scene { SceneNumber = "15A" },
                                    new Scene { SceneNumber = "2" },
                                    new Scene { SceneNumber = "30B" },
                                    new Scene { SceneNumber = "4B" },
                                    new Scene { SceneNumber = "4A" }
                                };

            foreach (var scene in sceneList.OrderBy(x => x, new SceneComparer()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(scene.SceneNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Scene
    {
        // TODO: Consider splitting SceneNumber into a e.g. a numeric "main scene" and an alpha "sub scene".
        public string SceneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class SceneComparer : IComparer<Scene>
    {
        // Assumes that a scene is either numeric, or numeric + alpha.
        private readonly Regex sceneRegEx = new Regex(@"(\d*)(\w*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        public int Compare(Scene x, Scene y)
        {
            var firstSceneMatch = this.sceneRegEx.Match(x.SceneNumber);

            var firstSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(firstSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
            var firstSceneAlpha = firstSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;

            var secondSceneMatch = this.sceneRegEx.Match(y.SceneNumber);

            var secondSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(secondSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
            var secondSceneAlpha = secondSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;

            if (firstSceneNumeric < secondSceneNumeric)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (firstSceneNumeric > secondSceneNumeric)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return string.CompareOrdinal(firstSceneAlpha, secondSceneAlpha);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
1
2
4A
4B
10
15A
30B
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

An `IComparer<string>` would look very similar:

```
public class SceneNumberComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    // Assumes that a scene is either numeric, or numeric + alpha.
    private readonly Regex sceneRegEx = new Regex(@"(\d*)(\w*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var firstSceneMatch = this.sceneRegEx.Match(x);

        var firstSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(firstSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
        var firstSceneAlpha = firstSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;

        var secondSceneMatch = this.sceneRegEx.Match(y);

        var secondSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(secondSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
        var secondSceneAlpha = secondSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;

        if (firstSceneNumeric < secondSceneNumeric)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (firstSceneNumeric > secondSceneNumeric)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return string.CompareOrdinal(firstSceneAlpha, secondSceneAlpha);
    }
}
```

... called by `.OrderBy(x => x.SceneNumber, new SceneNumberComparer())`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to implement the Compare method as follows:

```
public static char[] nums = "0123456789".ToCharArray();

public static int Compare(string x, string y)
{
    if (x.LastIndexOfAny(nums) > y.LastIndexOfAny(nums))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (x.LastIndexOfAny(nums) == y.LastIndexOfAny(nums))
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
    return -1;
}
```